# is it possible that getElementsByTagName doesn't actually return all the elements?

Tags: javascript

I know this is silly but i really don't understand what is going on, i am calling a simple `getElementsByTagName` from my js like this :

```
var script_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
//then i loop
for(a = 0; a < script_elements.length ; a++)
{
     alert(script_elements[a].getAttribute('src'));
}
```

but it doesn't alert all the `script` elements with `src` defined that exists, i thought probably the document isn't fully loaded that is why i was having this problem, and to be sure i added in the beginning before calling `getElementsByTagName` this `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML` and i do get the source code and nothing is missing, the only solution i found is to use regex and capture what i want but it is pretty dumb considering that JS has simple built in methods.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you running that script on `$(document).ready()` (or at the very bottom of the page, if not) ?

Comment: Try running your code inside this function: window.onload = function(){ }

Comment: Make sure it's inside $(document).ready() { //code } to make sure that the page is fully loaded before the JavaScript executes.

Comment: The `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML` trick isn't valid. The `innerHTML` content might not be present when the statement is executed even though it is there when the result is displayed (e.g. in a `console.log()` or `alert()`

Comment: Also, let us know which script reference it is not showing.

Comment: @DavidKhaykin he may not be using jQuery ..in which case `onload()` and sticking the script tag containing this code must go to the bottom.

Comment: @Vikram putting the script at the bottom of the page accomplishes the same thing with normal synchronous HTML parsing done by browsers. Either way same premise - make sure DOM is loaded before accessing it. Anyway it seems like everyone uses jQuery these days so I hope I didn't jump the gun with my assumption, although his code certainly doesn't have any jQuery in it.

Comment: The $(document).ready() did it thanks a lot again :D

Comment: @DavidKhaykin Mugiwara was indeed using jQuery :)

Comment: Awesome. Now can someone post it as the answer so this question has at least one correct answer posted? :)

Comment: @Mugiwara: You can post it as the answer, and accept it, too. It helps people who stumble on your question later to see the solution right away. Since you actually read the comments and tried it and got it working, I think you should do the honors ;)

Comment: @StephenThomas: Of course it is there when that statement is executed? Regardless of the output, the expression is always evaluated in the same way with the same DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was waiting for someone to do the honors and thus accept it, but since none did i will do it as it might help others, so thanks a lot to you guys the `$(document).ready()` did it :

```
$(document).ready(

    var script_elements = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
    for(a = 0; a < script_elements.length ; a++)
    {
       //treatment
    }

)
```

Answer (score -2):

From my experience, getElementsByTagName always returns all elements but alert does not always show an alert. I would use console.log instead of alert. That will always log the element.

I am curious about using getAttribute instead of the src property of the element.  I don't have a good reason for this, but I don't use getAttribute when there is a property in the dom that will work as well. Put another way, I only use getAttribute to access attributes that I define and the dom knows nothing about. My point is that I am weak on what getAttribute will return for the src attribute in every case, but I know that console.log will tell you, even if it is null which alert will not do (in my experience, I have not read the spec, so I do not know what alert is supposed to do)

For those concerned that you have to wait for the document to load, that is not my experience. Unless you put defer on the script tag, scripts load in sequence. As long as this script occurs in the document after the scripts that you want to inspect, you will see them.